# COOKIE | unable to read my cookie from php

Tags: php, cookies

I've some issues on getting my cookie back using plain PHP.

Here is the scenario:

- I set a cookie in PHP on page #1, then I send this page to the
  browser.
- Page #1 loads, and my cookie is there (tested with main browsers).
- From page #1, I navigate to another page #2 (same domain), which
  starts with another PHP code.
- On page #2  I read $_COOKIE[] but my cookie is not there.

It should be straightforward working with cookies, what am I doing wrong?

I've seen others posts, but nothing seems to work. My site is shared-hosted, and I've no problems with it. Thanks.

[php: $_COOKIE set-up and reading doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177395/php-cookie-set-up-and-reading-doesnt-work-properly)

**Page #1**

```
setcookie('ckuser', $token, strtotime( '+30 days' ), '/');   
$_COOKIE['ckuser']=$token; // even tried to save my cookie manually but didn't work
```

**Page #2**

```
$token= $_COOKIE['ckuser']; // this page is called from page #1, where cookie exist. $token has wrong data in it or null
```

Comment: Are you sure you get value for $token in Page #1. Try `var_dump($token)` in Page #1 before `setcookie()`.

Comment: Yes,  `setcookie()` works fine and the token is on the page. No matter what I set with `setcookie()`, $_COOKIE is always getting an old token.